# Sample all Instances of Customer within Timeseries Data

Tags: python, pyspark, sampling

I'm looking to sample from a pyspark dataframe that has customer data with a timeseries component, for exmaple:

| cust_id | efectv_dt | measurement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0457 | 2020-01-01 | 0.789 |
| 0457 | 2020-02-01 | 0.699 |
| 0457 | 2020-03-01 | 0.855 |
| 0361 | 2020-01-01 | 0.954 |
| 0361 | 2020-02-01 | 0.834 |
| ... | ... | ... |

In sampling, I would like the sample to include *all* date instances for a given customer if that customer is included in the sample. I'm aware I could do this in several steps, by first selecting the distinct set of customer IDs, sampling from this set, and then selecting values from the original dataset where the customer ID is included within the sample set of IDs.

However, I'm wondering if anyone knows of a more efficient way / a built-in function in pyspark to perform this type of sampling, or if there's a name for this particular type of sampling.

Comment: Does `sampleBy` solve your problem? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sampleBy.html

Comment: Unfortunately no. Stratified sampling does not work for this use-case.